# Prevent execution of script in a View when writing html tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have two html strings:

1. `<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>`
2. `1<br>2<br>3`

User enters these and I store then in my database. Then, I load theme from the database again and write theme in a view to show theme to the user.

Here's how I do it:

```
// 1
@MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>");  
// 2
@MvcHtmlString.Create("1<br>2<br>3");
```

And, here is the results on my view:

```
1.    A javascript dialog box pops up and shows the alert to the user.              
2.    1
      2
      3
```

In sample 1, user can enter a script and bring up a javascript alert and the user can see the following string:

```
"<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>"
```

That is OK, but in sample 2, the `<br>` tag does not work, and user will see this:

```
1<br>2<br>3
```

What can I do to have these outputs:

```
1:    "<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>"
2:    1
      2
      3
```

Note that I do not want to remove any part of user's data, because if a user is a developer and wants to show a script syntax, he should be allowed to.

Comment: You need to provide more code and explain what you need to achieve. From what you wrote, it's not clear whether the first example works the way you want or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, i like to use @Html.Raw

```
@Html.Raw("1<br>2<br>3")
```

for displaying html, and the output will be

```
1
2
3
```

---

```
@Html.Raw("<script>alert('s');</script>").ToHtmlString()
```

for displaying text , by adding ToHtmlString() , and the output will be

```
<script>alert('s');</script>
```